# How can I set Tmux pane title, like "zsh-prompt : powerlevel9k"?

Tags: command-line, git, zsh, tmux

When I open many panes in Tmux, and do something like `ls` or `git status`, the screen has a lot of prompt like:

[image: many prompt on screen]

I want to have this complex prompt on the top of pane, and only `#` on current line.

Like:

[image: ideal tmux pane]

How can I do this?
I am using iTerm2 with zsh powerlevel9k theme.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [script](https://github.com/cocobear/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/functions/pane-border-format.sh) to implement this.

just put this in .tmux.conf:

```
set -g pane-border-format '#(sh ~/.config/functions/pane-border-format.sh \
  --pane-current-path=#{pane_current_path} \
  --pane-active=#{pane_active})'
```

script modified from https://www.markneuburger.com/git-statuses-in-tmux-panes/